# how to use DataBinder.Eval of repeater within asp.net button's OnClientClick javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in my asp.net webform. In "ItemTemplate" of the repater i added a asp:button. And i write the following code on "OnClientClick" event of the button.

```
//This is javascript function
function DeleteGroup(groupID){
return confirm('Do you want to delete ' + groupID);

//This is asp.net page code<br>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete"
OnClientClick="
return DeleteGroup(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GrupID") %>); 
" />
```

I have tried many variant of OnClientClick but i couldnt success it.
How can i pass "GoupID" value which i retrive from database to javascript function "DeleteGroup"?

Comment: There is a typo in your code above, you have used "GrupID" instead of "GroupID" in the DataBinder.Eval - Could that affect your tests?

Comment: @bgs264 It does not have any effect. "GrupID" is datafieldname on my database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For VB:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='<%# "return DeleteGroup(" & Eval("GroupID") & ");" %>' />
```

For C#:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='<%# "return DeleteGroup(" + Eval("GroupID") + ");" %>' />
```

Comment: It gives an error: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'object'

Comment: Actually, I use C# so i replaced '&' with '+' and it works now. Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the answer slightly to include both versions for others who stumble across this.

Comment: I am using `OnClientClick='<%# "return CommentPopup(" + Eval("Comments") + ");" %>'` but its not working. Any solutions?

Comment: If someone is wondering how to be able to pass a string parameter as well, following worked for me `OnClientClick='<%# "SomeMethod(" + Eval("ID") + ", &apos;" + Eval("Name") + "&apos;); return false;" %>'`