# Asp.net Repeater OnClientClick() doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using repeater control and have added following snippet to show one of the columns. I am trying to show Linkbutton Text in an alert box which is set by `Eval("Comments")`. I have already checked [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844230/how-to-use-databinder-eval-of-repeater-within-asp-net-buttons-onclientclick-jav) question and no luck yet.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkComments" OnClientClick='<%# "CommentPopup(" + Eval("Comments") + ");" %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comments") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
```

**JS Code**

```
Function CommentPopup (element) 
{ 
   alert(element); // For testing purpose
}
```

The function is not triggered when I click on the linkbutton. Is anything wrong with syntax?

Aaprt from this, is it feasible to pass linkbutton control like `OnClientClick='return CommentPopup(this);'` and then accesss its text using `this.text` or `this.val()`?

**Update**: Chrome's Console shows

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the comments in quotes.

Markup tends to break when escaping quotes in my experience, but give the code below a try.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkComments" OnClientClick='<%# "CommentPopup(\"" + Eval("Comments") + "\");" %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comments") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
```

If it's still breaking you may need to adjust the building of your string using string.format, or create a public function in the codebehind that will take in the comment as a parameter, and output the desired string.

Answer (score 1):

"Function" should be "function". Open up the developer tools of your browser, if you have syntax errors, they will show up there.
On the second question, yes, it is, just don't use "this.val()", because val is a jQuery method, not native JavaScript.

Comment: Its 'function' in my code. Auto-corrected by the  browser. My bad. BTW what's JS alternative for val() which will server my purpose?